Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle, but no problems are detected when validating plug-ins
I inherited an Eclipse RCP application (org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application) from a colleague.
I tried to launch the application through MyApp.product > Launch an Eclipse application but the application won't run and this is an excerpt of the stack trace:
!ENTRY com.jaspersoft.studio 4 0 2024-04-16 09:25:42.543
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.jaspersoft.studio [28]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: net.sf.jasperreports.samples; bundle-version="6.12.0"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: net.sf.jasperreports.samples; bundle-version="6.12.0.final"; singleton:="true"
       net.sf.jasperreports.samples [74]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: net.sf.jasperreports; bundle-version="6.12.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: net.sf.jasperreports; bundle-version="6.12.0.final"; singleton:="true"
              net.sf.jasperreports [73]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.jaspersoft.studio.bundles.batik; bundle-version="1.11.0"; visibility:="reexport"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.jaspersoft.studio.bundles.batik; bundle-version="1.11.0.b02"
                     com.jaspersoft.studio.bundles.batik [31]
                       No resolution report for the bundle.                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.jaspersoft.studio.bundles.poi; bundle-version="4.1.1"; visibility:="reexport"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.jaspersoft.studio.bundles.poi; bundle-version="4.1.1.b01"
                     com.jaspersoft.studio.bundles.poi [39]
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.batik.anim.dom
                         -> Export-Package: org.apache.batik.anim.dom; bundle-symbolic-name="com.jaspersoft.studio.bundles.batik"; bundle-version="1.11.0.b02"; version="0.0.0"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.batik.gvt
                         -> Export-Package: org.apache.batik.gvt; bundle-symbolic-name="com.jaspersoft.studio.bundles.batik"; bundle-version="1.11.0.b02"; version="0.0.0"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.batik.bridge
                         -> Export-Package: org.apache.batik.bridge; bundle-symbolic-name="com.jaspersoft.studio.bundles.batik"; bundle-version="1.11.0.b02"; version="0.0.0"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.batik.ext.awt
                         -> Export-Package: org.apache.batik.ext.awt; bundle-symbolic-name="com.jaspersoft.studio.bundles.batik"; bundle-version="1.11.0.b02"; version="0.0.0"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.renderable
                         -> Export-Package: org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.renderable; bundle-symbolic-name="com.jaspersoft.studio.bundles.batik"; bundle-version="1.11.0.b02"; version="0.0.0"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.batik.util
                         -> Export-Package: org.apache.batik.util; bundle-symbolic-name="com.jaspersoft.studio.bundles.batik"; bundle-version="1.11.0.b02"; version="0.0.0"
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.commons.lang
                  -> Export-Package: org.apache.commons.lang; bundle-symbolic-name="com.jaspersoft.studio"; bundle-version="6.12.0.final"; version="0.0.0"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: net.sf.jasperreports; bundle-version="6.12.0"; visibility:="reexport"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: net.sf.jasperreports; bundle-version="6.12.0.final"; singleton:="true"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.jaspersoft.studio.properties; bundle-version="6.12.0"; visibility:="reexport"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.jaspersoft.studio.properties; bundle-version="6.12.0.final"; singleton:="true"
       com.jaspersoft.studio.properties [41]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.wb.swt
           -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.wb.swt; bundle-symbolic-name="net.sf.jasperreports"; bundle-version="6.12.0.final"; version="0.0.0"; uses:="org.eclipse.swt.graphics,org.eclipse.jface.resource"
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: net.sf.jasperreports; bundle-version="6.12.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: net.sf.jasperreports; bundle-version="6.12.0.final"; singleton:="true"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.pde.ui
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.pde.ui; bundle-version="3.15.100.v20240215-1631"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.pde.ui [287]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.bndtools.templating; version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)"
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: biz.aQute.resolve; version="[9.0.0,10.0.0)"
           -> Export-Package: biz.aQute.resolve; bundle-symbolic-name="biz.aQute.resolve"; bnd-plugins="true"; bundle-version="7.0.0.202310060912"; version="9.0.0"; uses:="aQute.bnd.build,aQute.bnd.build.model,aQute.bnd.build.model.clauses,aQute.bnd.build.model.conversions,aQute.bnd.header,aQute.bnd.help.instructions,aQute.bnd.osgi,aQute.bnd.osgi.repository,aQute.bnd.osgi.resource,aQute.bnd.result,aQute.bnd.service,aQute.bnd.service.resolve.hook,aQute.bnd.util.dto,aQute.bnd.version,aQute.service.reporter,org.osgi.framework,org.osgi.resource,org.osgi.service.log,org.osgi.service.repository,org.osgi.service.resolver"
              biz.aQute.resolve [10]
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: aQute.bnd.deployer.repository; version="[5.0.0,6.0.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:2073)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2064)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2004)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1967)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1883)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:341)

Note that when I click on Run configurations > Plug-ins > Validate Plug-ins no problems are detected:

I expected the problems to be detected while validating plug-ins since the stack trace above suggests there are issues due to (missing?) plug-ins. How can I solve? In case you need it, this is the MANIFEST.MF file:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Analyzer
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.my-company.my-appanalyzer;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
  swing2swt.jar
Bundle-Activator: com.my-company.my-appanalyzer.managers.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: My Company
Export-Package: com.my-company.analyzer.log.log4j,
  com.my-company.my-appanalyzer.data,
  com.my-company.my-appanalyzer.dialogs,
  com.my-company.my-appanalyzer.handlers,
  com.my-company.my-appanalyzer.listeners,
  com.my-company.my-appanalyzer.managers,
  com.my-company.my-appanalyzer.parts,
  com.my-company.my-appanalyzer.providers,
  com.my-company.my-appanalyzer.table,
  com.my-company.my-appanalyzer.utils,
  com.my-company.my-appanalyzer.utils.filesystem,
  com.my-company.my-appanalyzer.views
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench;bundle-version="1.0.1",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.services;bundle-version="1.0.1",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench;bundle-version="1.0.2",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.di,
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.di;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts;bundle-version="1.3.1",
 org.eclipse.nebula.visualization.xygraph;bundle-version="3.1.0",
 org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.glazedlists;bundle-version="2.0.0",
 ca.odell.glazedlists;bundle-version="1.9.0",
 org.eclipse.osgi.services,
 org.eclipse.emf.common.ui;bundle-version="2.13.0",
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi;bundle-version="2.14.0",
 com.my-company.tmlibrary,
 com.my-company.applicationManager;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 org.eclipse.draw2d,
 org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.core;bundle-version="2.0.0",
 org.apache.poi,
 org.eclipse.osgi;bundle-version="3.12.0",
 org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxen;bundle-version="1.1.6"
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Import-Package: com.my-company.application.configurations,
 com.my-company.tmlibrary.configuration,
 com.my-company.tmlibrary.files,
 com.my-company.tmlibrary.files.my-app,
 com.my-company.tmlibrary.utils,
 com.my-company.tool.utils,
 com.my-company.my-appanalyzer.managers,
 javax.annotation;version="1.0.0",
 javax.inject;version="1.0.0",
 org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar;version="1.6.0",
 org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.gzip;version="1.6.0",
 org.eclipse.core.runtime;version="3.5.0",
 org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs,
 org.eclipse.e4.core.services.events,
 org.eclipse.equinox.app;version="1.1.0"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8


EDIT I do have a target platform file (.target) activated, as you can see below:



This is its content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?>
<target name="my-target-definition" sequenceNumber="15">
    <locations>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
            <unit id="org.eclipse.orbit.maven.osgi.all.feature.group" version="4.31.0.v20240227-0900"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.orbit.maven.osgi.all.source.feature.group" version="4.31.0.v20240227-0900"/>
            <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/simrel/maven-osgi/release/4.31.0/"/>
        </location>
        <location path="C:\Users\John\Desktop\eclipse_rcp_dev\plugins" type="Directory"/>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.eclipselink.feature.feature.group" version="1.4.203.v202104080213"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.feature.feature.group" version="1.5.201.v202301061019"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.feature.feature.group" version="3.4.101.v202308172102"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.feature.feature.group" version="3.7.0.v202308172102"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jpt.jpadiagrameditor.feature.feature.group" version="1.2.300.v202307260736"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jsf.feature.feature.group" version="3.13.0.v202308300413"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.common.fproj.enablement.jdt.feature.group" version="3.29.0.v202308161955"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_ui.feature.feature.group" version="3.33.0.v202401080452"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.jsf.apache.trinidad.tagsupport.feature.feature.group" version="2.8.0.v202307262303"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.server_adapters.ext.feature.feature.group" version="3.4.900.v202402192305"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.server_adapters.feature.feature.group" version="3.33.0.v202401292308"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.server_ui.feature.feature.group" version="3.4.500.v202401292331"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.web_js_support.feature.feature.group" version="3.32.0.v202309190220"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.web_ui.feature.feature.group" version="3.33.0.v202402161256"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.webpageeditor.feature.feature.group" version="2.12.0.v202307262216"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2tools.feature.feature.group" version="1.2.0.v202308010354"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.feature.feature.group" version="1.1.1200.v202311232240"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.dom.feature.feature.group" version="1.0.600.v202308010354"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.feature.feature.group" version="1.2.1000.v202311280000"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group" version="2.6.0.20240220-1109"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.m2e.feature.source.feature.group" version="2.6.0.20240220-1109"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group" version="2.6.0.20240217-1525"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.m2e.pde.feature.feature.group" version="2.3.1.20240203-0902"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.m2e.pde.feature.source.feature.group" version="2.3.1.20240203-0902"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.m2e.sdk.feature.feature.group" version="2.6.0.20240220-1109"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.feature.feature.group" version="1.6.1.20231024-1618"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jaxrs.feature.feature.group" version="1.6.1.20231024-1618"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa.feature.feature.group" version="1.6.1.20231024-1618"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jsf.feature.feature.group" version="1.6.1.20231024-1618"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.php.composer.feature.group" version="8.2.0.202311292129"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.php.feature.group" version="8.2.0.202311292129"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.rap.tools.feature.feature.group" version="3.28.0.20240306-1200"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.embedder.node.feature.feature.group" version="1.0.7.202310251358"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.feature.feature.group" version="1.3.3.202311211923"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.common.fproj.feature.group" version="3.7.4.v202308161955"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.chromium.debug.feature.feature.group" version="0.7.0.v202307190351"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.feature.feature.group" version="2.4.500.v202307190318"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.server_adapters.feature.feature.group" version="3.33.0.v202401292308"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.web_js_support.feature.feature.group" version="3.33.0.v202403030558"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature.feature.group" version="3.31.0.v202403030558"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group" version="3.33.0.v202402030243"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.xsl.feature.feature.group" version="1.3.1500.v202307260701"/>
            <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest"/>
        </location>
        <location path="C:\Users\John\Desktop\eclipse\plugins" type="Directory"/>
    </locations>
</target>

In the stack trace the first error is:

Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: net.sf.jasperreports.samples; bundle-version="6.12.0"

So, according to this answer, I navigated to MyApp.product > Contents and tried to Add net.sf.jasperreports.samples, but no plug-in is detected:

Also, I hit Add required plug-ins but this won't fix.

I don't think validate plug-ins is able to check everything. The log shows you have two versions of the org.eclipse.jetty.util plugin, version 12.0.6 which is from Eclipse 4.31 and version 9.4.5 from Eclipse 4.7. At a guess (and this is just a guess) the RCP needs to be built on a target platform which is just Eclipse 4.7 and can't be built against the current 4.31 without changes.

@greg-449 This won't fix

"This won't fix" - What exactly did you do? It seems something is wrong with your target platform you configured in the preferences Plug-in Development > Target Platform (as already greg-449 said; maybe you just missed to set the correct target platform).

@howlger I edited my post with further explanations, please check it out

That new image seems to be just the plug-in dependencies. As we have already said the problem looks like it is what is in the Target Platform.

You should have a .target file (e.g. like this one), likely outside of the project. Open it and activate it.

@greg-449 Good morninig. I do have a target platform activated. I edited my post with further information, please check it out thank you

https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/ refers now to Eclipse 2024-03 (4.31) for which your application needs to be adapted. In your MANIFEST.MF the Require-Bundle and Import-Package dependencies are specified without or only with the minimum version instead of with a version range (e.g. bundle-version="2.14.0" instead of bundle-version="[2.14.0,3.0.0)"; see semantic versioning) which leads to errors at runtime that could have been detected at compile time.

In your .product file you can only add things that are provided by your target platform.

There are helpful tutorials for Eclipse RCP development here: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/eclipse.html

@howlger Hello. I have already read thise Vogella's tutorials, but I still can't figure out how to solve properly my issue. Any other advice? Also,  since only the plug-ins provided by my target platform can be added in the "plug-ins selection" panel, how can I edit my target platform in order to fix those issues?

Your target platform needs to provide net.sf.jasperreports.samples. https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/ does not contain it and I'm not aware of a p2 repository containing it.
